# Python - slow speed when extracting numbers/words from a string

Tags: python, regex

Noob here trying to learn python by doing a project as I don't learn well from books.

I am using a huge lump of code to perform what seems to me to be a small operation -

I want to extract 4 variables from the following string

```
'Miami 0, New England 28'
```

(variables being home_team, away_team, home_score, away_score)

My program is running pretty slow and I think it might be this bit of code.  I guess I am looking for the quickest/most efficient way of doing this.

Would regex be quicker? Thanks

Comment: What bit of code?  You haven't showed us any code there.  Can you post the code that you're using to parse that text?

Comment: Yes regexes are very fast.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like your text could be split twice.  First on `,` and next on whitespace:

```
info1,info2 = s.split(',')
home,home_score = info1.rsplit(None,1)
away,away_score = info2.rsplit(None,1)
```

e.g.:

```
>>> s = 'Miami 0, New England 28'
>>> info1,info2 = s.split(',')
>>> home,home_score = info1.rsplit(None,1)
>>> away,away_score = info2.rsplit(None,1)
>>> print [home,home_score,away,away_score]
['Miami', '0', ' New England', '28']
```

You *could* do this with regex without too much difficulty -- but you pay for it in terms of readability.

Comment: why am i so dumb.  I have spent about 3 hours thinking I needed to separate the numbers and text without realising there is whitespace between them.

Comment: @user2073606 -- It was slightly more complicated than I just posted.  (I forgot that the team name could have whitespace in it as well).  The fix was to `rsplit` instead of `split` and to only allow the string to be split once.

Comment: I think you should split on `', '`, cause you don't want a leading space in the away team name

Answer (score 0):

In case you do want a regex:

```
import re

s='Miami 0, New England 28'
l=re.findall(r'^([^\d]+)\s(\d+)\s*,\s*([^\d]+)\s(\d+)',s)
hm_team,away_team,hm_score,away_score=l[0]

print l
```

Prints `[('Miami', '0', 'New England', '28')]` and assigns those values to the variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

reg = re.compile('\s*(\D+?)\s*(\d+)'
                 '[,;:.#=@\s]*'
                 '(\D+?)\s*(\d+)'
                 '\s*')

for s in ('Miami 0, New England 28',
          'Miami0,New England28  ',
          '  Miami    0   . New England28',
          'Miami 0 ; New England 28',
          'Miami0#New England28  ',
          '  Miami 0   @ New England28'):

    print reg.search(s).groups()
```

result

```
('Miami', '0', 'New England', '28')
('Miami', '0', 'New England', '28')
('Miami', '0', 'New England', '28')
('Miami', '0', 'New England', '28')
('Miami', '0', 'New England', '28')
('Miami', '0', 'New England', '28')
```

`'\D'` means 'no digit'